# Drawing Shapes outside paintComponent() (java)

Tags: java, graphics

I'm new to graphics in java and am having difficulty grasping the whole concept of drawing all your graphics from one method (paintComponent ()). I was just curious to see if we can draw graphics outside the paintComponent. Is that even possible? is it possible to write a line in the main method like:
 fillRect(100,100, 500,400); 
and have it draw a rectangle?
If it is possible, is it conventional according to Java?

Basically, I'm asking if you can draw graphics outside the paintComponent class and is it conventional.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw to a `BufferedImage`, but if you want it drawn on the screen then generally, you'll need to use `paintComponent`.  You can pass the instance of `Graphics` which is passed into `paintComponent` to other classes which can do more complex operations, but you should never maintain a reference that instance or try painting outside of a paint cycle context.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details

If you need more control over the paint process you could also use a `BufferStrategy`

See [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) for more details

Things you should know:

- Swing uses a "passive rendering" approach, this means that painting occurs when the paint system decides it needs to be done. This is why you MUST perform your painting within the context of a paint cycle (ie - in the `paintComponent` method)
- `BufferStrategy` uses a "active rendering" approach, which gives you complete control of the painting process, but it's not capable of painting Swing components